# Why RISCV choose "push and pop" RAS for coroutines?

Tags: cpu-architecture, coroutine, riscv

In riscv-spec-2.2, it provide the following truth table for Return Address Stack (RAS) behavior:

> ```
> rd     rs1     rs1=rd  RAS action
> !link  !link   -       none
> !link  link    -       pop
> link   !link   -       push
> link   link    0       push and pop
> link   link    1       push
> ```

I'm confused about the "**push and pop**" case, where riscv-spec-2.2 says it's used to support coroutines:

> When two different link registers (x1 and x5) are given as rs1 and rd, then the RAS is both pushed and popped to support coroutines"

I also found there is a discussion about the RAS truth table in riscv mailing list, but it didn't explain why "**push and pop**" for RAS could help coroutines (but it mentioned that Alpha also have this kind of hint for coroutines):

https://groups.google.com/a/groups.riscv.org/d/msg/isa-dev/uZUTszCtgAA/f3jDhbjEAAAJ

In my understanding, a "**push and pop**" of RAS will replace the top entry of RAS. Therefore, when the software returning from coroutine, there will be a miss-predict since the correct return address (at RAS top entry in the beginning) was replaced. It seems doesn't have any benefit to perform "**push and pop**" compare to a simple "**push**".

Why RISCV choose to "**push and pop**" RAS for coroutines ?

Comment: Yes, there is a mispredict if coroutine 2 returns, but you can't do anything about that. There is a good prediction if the coroutine 2 switches back to the coroutine 1 before returning. At that point, the predictor stack is exactly what it was before the coroutine 1 switched to coroutine 2. If you always push, then the predictor stack will *always* mispredict. It won't be correct for coroutine 2, and it won't be correct for coroutine 1 either.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I got your point. I didn't consider that switch back from coroutine2 to coroutine1 will also use "**push and pop**". But I don't understand why RAS will be exactly it was after switching. I think there will be one miss prediction for the return of the function invoking coroutine2, since the top entry of RAS was replaced to the address of coroutine_2 for its switching (i.e, an "**push and pop**"). But there would be no miss prediction for the caller of this function.

Comment: Coroutine transfer pops the return address and predicts it, then pushes the caller's address. The initial transfer from coroutine1 to coroutine2 is mispredicted (since it predicts coroutine1's caller). The transfer from coroutine2 back to coroutine1 is predicted correctly. A subsequent transfer from coroutine1 to coroutine2 is also predicted correctly. The pattern is designed for the case of two coroutines jumping back and forth. If a coroutine transfer changed the stack depth, then two coroutines transferring back and forth would eat up the entire RAS.